# Scheduled logoff scripts

Tags: script, batch, scheduled-tasks, active-directory, tasks

I wondered if it was possible to launch a logoff script only, for example, every friday. Can this task be scheduled in Active Directory or must I programm a scripts that adds and remove it every friday ?

Comment: This question is a [possible duplicate](http://serverfault.com/questions/67543/how-can-i-automatically-log-out-all-machines-on-a-windows-domain) of an older question of mine over on Server Fault.

Answer (score 0):

I use something like that currently. I have a batch file with a bunch of `shutdown /r /m \\computername /t 0` statements in it, which actually restarts the computers, but same thing. As long as your server has access to the computer, which it should (being the domain controller and all), then it should work. And you can set it to run how ever often you want.